# Salvage Data from Corrupted MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I've a corrupted Mongo database that no matter what I tried cannot be recovered (tried running with repair, didn't work).

Question is, is there anyway to salvage at least some of the data from the collection files? the database had about 10 millions documents and I'd like to salvage as many as possible.

MongoDump used to be able to work directly against the database files, but since version 3.0 and WiredTiger it doesn't support this anymore. is there any other way to work directly against the collection files and read at least some of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so we found a pretty awesome solution:

- Download [WiredTiger source](https://snappy.angeloflogic.com/downloads/)
- Download and install Python
- Download [SCONS](https://snappy.angeloflogic.com/downloads/)
- Download [Snappy compressor](https://snappy.angeloflogic.com/downloads/)
- Put the snappy header files under "WiredTiger source folder"\include
- Put the snappy dll and lib files under "WiredTiger source folder"\lib
- Put the snappy dll and lib files under "WiredTiger source folder"\ (rename the dll without the 32 or 64, so its only: snappy.dll and snappy.lib)
- Run the scons.bat (which is located under: "python install folder"\Scripts) so that the working directory is the WiredTiger source folder
- We had to updated the SConstruct file in the WiredTiger source folder  so that instead of the following line:

  > useSnappy = GetOption("snappy")
- We used the following line:

  > useSnappy = "THE WIREDTIGER SOURCE FOLDER"
- The output of this whole process is a wt.exe executable that supports the snappy compressor
- We then used wt.exe salvage FILE-NAME for each *.wt file in the Mongo original folder
- We had to run the wt.exe from the actual MongoDB folder otherwise it didn't work for us, AND if your db folder is on a network share, you must first map it to a network drive

After running wt.exe salvage on all *.wt files we were able to run MongoDB again.

hooray!

Comment: Hi @sternr, this article can is God send because i am in the same world of trouble as you were 4 years back :). Links are not working, or rather pointing to the same page.. trying to follow the steps..

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem where mongod would not start due to a corruption in one of the index files.

After taking a snapshot of the corrupted files, I was able to run a repair by deleting the corrupted index file.

```
rm index-2--2929746126664852663.wt
mongod --repair --storageEngine wiredTiger
```

Mongod then ran a verify and salvage operation on a corrupted collection file and shut itself down.