# Error repairing MongoDB database - Verify failed on uri table

Tags: mongodb

Suddenly my mongodb server has stopped working on my Mac and I just try to start it again It'll throw me an error described here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/WT-4135.

So run a database repair and I keep getting this error,

```
2018-06-19T13:18:38.428+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] repairDatabase pdg_db
2018-06-19T13:18:38.428+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Repairing collection ipd_db.app_sessions
2018-06-19T13:18:38.428+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Verify failed on uri table:collection-1--4208304830224804148. Running a salvage operation.
2018-06-19T13:18:38.428+0530 F -        [initandlisten] Invariant failure rs.get() src/mongo/db/catalog/database_impl.cpp 226
```

So I can't even start the server. As my understanding if I drop `pdg_db` this issue will be solved. But how to drop database without running the mongodb server? Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Salvage Data from Corrupted MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974345/salvage-data-from-corrupted-mongodb)

Comment: @Neodan It's not working, I already tested it and it's for windows. This is a Mac. Thanks